# JavaScript custom function not applying to the database object

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a price value from a SQLLITE db. The data type was in DB was REAL.

I'm getting the value and put it to a text box using jQuery.

```
$(current_tr).find('.unit_price').val(row.unit_price);
```

this code is working fine with out any errors and I can see the amount in the text box. But due to Its a price I need to format it to as a price with 2 decimal places. I have found a custom function to do this from Stackoverflow.

```
String.prototype.toPrice = function () {
    var v;
    if (/^\d+(,\d+)$/.test(this))
        v = this.replace(/,/, '.');
    else if (/^\d+((,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)?$/.test(this))
        v = this.replace(/,/g, "");
    else if (/^\d+((.\d{3})*(,\d+)?)?$/.test(this))
        v = this.replace(/\./g, "").replace(/,/, ".");
    var x = parseFloat(v).toFixed(2).toString().split("."),
    x1 = x[0],
    x2 = ((x.length == 2) ? "." + x[1] : ".00"),
    exp = /^([0-9]+)(\d{3})/;
    while (exp.test(x1))
        x1 = x1.replace(exp, "$1" + "," + "$2");
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

The function is working in following condition without any error.

```
$(current_tr).find('.unit_price').val('5000'.toPrice());
```

But I tried to apply it to the db value its not returning anything. The textbox is getting blank. The following ways I have tired.

```
$(current_tr).find('.unit_price').val(row.unit_price.toPrice());

$(current_tr).find('.unit_price').val((row.unit_price).toString().toPrice());
```

But non of its working for DB object. Is there any mistake in my way?

Comment: Does the DB value have any currency character prefixed to it? ($5000 vs 5000)

Comment: not its a (REAL) digits only. Ex: 5000

Comment: Instead of using .toString() try (row.unit_price + '').toPrice()

Comment: Maybe row.unit_price is comming with some decimals separated with dot(.)? The regexp looks like only Works with comma(,)

Comment: Yes looks something wrong with the function. When I tried this it works fine.
return parseFloat(this).toFixed(2);